# SwiftUI Form & Section items do not have equal height?

Tags: swiftui

I am using a SwiftUI Form view but the 1st item in the Section of multiple items ("Account" in RED) has a shorter height than the following two items "Notifications" & "Preferences".

[image]

I tried adding a .frame(height: ) modifier to SettingsItem's VStack but that didn't force all the items to have the same height.

The only way the different sections look correct is if it's a single item in its own section, see the image below where the text "Password" is even inside its container but 3 items sharing a section are not even.

[image]

2 QUESTIONS

1. How can I make all items in a section have the same vertical height.
2. Is it possible to remove the corner radius so that the form has sharp edges? I need to get rid of the corner radius because I will add negative 20 padding leading & trailing so that each item expands to the edge of the screen so I don't want to see rounded corners.

```
struct Settings: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Form {
                Section(header: Text("ACCOUNT SETTINGS")
                    .foregroundColor(.gray)) {
                        SettingsItem(showDivider: true, text: "Account")
                        SettingsItem(showDivider: true, text: "Notifications")
                        SettingsItem(showDivider: false, text: "Preferences")
                    }
                Section(header: Text("SECURITY")
                    .foregroundColor(.gray)) {
                        SettingsItem(showDivider: false, text: "Password")
                    }
                
                Section(header: Text("ABOUT")
                    .foregroundColor(.gray)) {
                        SettingsItem(showDivider: true, text: "FAQ")
                        SettingsItem(showDivider: true, text: "About")
                        SettingsItem(showDivider: false, text: "Contact")
                    }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```
struct SettingsItem: View {
    let showDivider: Bool
    var text: String

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            HStack {
                Text(text)
                    .font(.system(size: 18, weight: .regular))
                    .foregroundColor(.gray)
                Spacer()
                Image(systemName: "chevron.right")
                    .font(.system(size: 16, weight: .bold))
                    .foregroundColor(.gray)
            }
            if showDivider {
                Divider()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure why you are adding a Divider() to some of your items? SwiftUI will automatically add those dividers if there are more than one items. If you get rid of the Divider the items will be vertically aligned.

Comment: To remove the corner radius you can simply use `.listStyle(_:)`to style the form. See example here: https://sarunw.com/posts/swiftui-list-style/. This way you don't need a negativ padding.

Answer (score 1):

Removing the dividers fixes the problem:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Form {
                Section("ACCOUNT SETTINGS") {
                    SettingsItem(text: "Account")
                    SettingsItem(text: "Notifications")
                    SettingsItem(text: "Preferences")
                }
                Section("SECURITY") {
                    SettingsItem(text: "Password")
                }
                
                Section("ABOUT") {
                    SettingsItem(text: "FAQ")
                    SettingsItem(text: "About")
                    SettingsItem(text: "Contact")
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
}
struct SettingsItem: View {
    var text: String
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            HStack {
                Text(text)
                    .font(.system(size: 18, weight: .regular))
                    .foregroundColor(.gray)
                Spacer()
                Image(systemName: "chevron.right")
                    .font(.system(size: 16, weight: .bold))
                    .foregroundColor(.gray)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image]